# Initial value problem for PDE wave equation using D'Alembert's formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u(x,t)=c^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,t) , \qquad -\infty<x<\infty, \qquad t>0,$$
\begin{equation}u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}u_t(x,0)=\cos(2x)\end{equation}
I used D'Alembert's formula and obtained the following:
\begin{equation}u(x,t)=e^{x^2+c^2t^2}[\cosh(2xct)]+\frac{1}{2c}(\cos(2x)\sin(2ct))\end{equation}
this may be correct so far, but my prof said something about extending the solution into the $x<0$ region as D'Alembert's formula is only true for $x>0$.  Can someone explain this and help me extend the solution? If D'Alembert's formula is true for $x>0$, why would it not be good for $x<0$?

Comment: You may have misunderstood your Prof. Noting in [d'Al$\color{red}{e}$mbert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) indicates that it is valid only for $x>0\,.$

Comment: *Nothing ... (typo of mine).

Comment: The solution is symmetric in x: $u(x,t)=u(-x,t)$
No restriction $x \ge 0$ exists

Comment: Hello, gpmath.  Thank you for the answer - also to Kurt G.  I am struggling to understand this type of problem.  After much time on the internet and with books, so far I know that the wave equation is modeling a right moving wave and a left moving wave. Evidently, we need to assume that the wave will bounce off of a wall which will then add or subtract to the existing waves. But if the f(x) and g(x) functions are odd then the reflected wave will cancel out and we do not need to consider the reflected wave. Both f and g are even functions. Can you explain ?